# Access this.refs / lwc:refs="" when testing in jest?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom, lwc-jest

I am attempting to use `this.refs` from with a jest test like this:

```html
<template>
  <input lwc:ref="inputEl" />
</template>
```

```js
// input.test.js
import { createElement } from 'lwc'
import InputLwc from 'c/input'

let element
describe('Input', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    while (document.body.firstChild) {
      document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild)
    }
  })

  beforeEach(() => {
    element = createElement('c-input', {
      is: InputLwc,
    })
    document.body.appendChild(element)
  })

  it('should update value', async () => {
    // unable to access this.refs / element.refs?
    console.log('refs ', element.refs) // undefined
    console.log('shadowRoot.refs ', element.shadowRoot.refs) // undefined
    console.log('inputEl ', element.refs.inputEl) // undefined
  })
})
```

Yes, I can choose to use `querySelector` here, but given the ease of use `this.refs` gives, it would be handy to have access to it in jest. I assume it is unavailable due to the private nature of `this.refs`.

Another work around could include adding an `@api` getter on the LWC, but that feels wrong and potentially overkill to be applied to all and any LWC that is being tested in jest.

Using the [`@lwc/jest-*`](https://github.com/salesforce/lwc-test) (`v14.1.0`) packages with `synthetic` DOM to mimic the on platform environment.

Comment: As per [this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_templaterefs.htm&release=242&type=5) document, If you call `this.refs` for a nonexistent ref, it returns undefined.   Try this: `console.log('inputEl ', this.refs.inputEl);`

Comment: Your Jest test should treat the component as a black box. Delving into the internals of the component is the wrong approach.